# Mysql and Putty - ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, putty

Im fairly new at mysql at command line level. unfortunately the assignment i have been set means i have to use command line.  I am accessing the schools server via PuTTY. log on no problems them type mysql -p, log in fine but then when i go to create the database i get the 1044 error. i have also tried root but no luck either.

```
login as: 10081552
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Last login: Sat Dec  7 16:04:24 GMT 2013 from 90.218.202.89 on ssh
Last login: Sat Dec  7 16:04:29 2013 from 90.218.202.89
10081552@sots ~ $ mysql -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8636
Server version: 5.0.90-log Gentoo Linux mysql-5.0.90-r2

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> create database hello;
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '10081552'@'localhost' to database 'hello'
mysql>
```

I checked the privileges and they seem fine (i think)

```
mysql> show grants;

| Grants for 10081552@localhost                                                                                                            

 GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '10081552'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*removed the  hash'                     |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES ON `10081552`.* TO '10081552'@'localhost' |

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

so I am sure its something I am doing wrong but can anyone tell me why I am unable to create anything. as I said early I am new to command line but not mysql or databases in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I checked the privileges and they seem fine*

The privileges are **not fine** for what you're trying to do. `GRANT`s for your user `10081552@localhost` clearly show that it has these privileges **only** in a database named `10081552`

```
GRANT ... ON `10081552`.* TO '10081552'@'localhost' 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Therefore you can successfully create tables in that particular database e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world(id INT);
```

But you're not allowed to create new databases.

Comment: oh my, how was i being so dumb. thank you so much for getting back to me. i was in the understand that i had to build the database. just check show databases and there was my database. thank you so much. long day

Answer (score 0):

To create a databases you must use the root username and password

Comment: You don't have to be root. You have to be a user with the rights to create a Database